# Openfaces Drop Down field - Block key in activity

Tags: jsf, openfaces

Is there any way to block the key in activity in [Openfaces Drop Down](http://openfaces.org/demo/dropdownfield/DropDownField_client.jsf) field. I want the Openfaces Drop Down Field to behave like a select one menu. Unfortunately i couldn't switch over to [Select One Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

I have checked the Openfaces documentation, but the component doesn't have any attribute related to that. Please help.

**Edit** - I am using JSF 1.2 and Openfaces 2.0

Answer (score 0):

There is one separate component "selectOneMenu" for such issues. You can read more here: http://wiki.openfaces.org/display/OF/SelectOneMenu+2.x+%28Incomplete%29